# How many nonnegative integers $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ satisfy $2x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = n$?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Can anyone give some hints about the following question?

> How many nonnegative integers $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ satisfy $2x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = n$?

Normally this kind of question uses stars and bars but there are $2x_1$, which I don’t know how to handle. Help please!

Ps :I think may be we can use recurrence relation.

Comment: What is that $n$ ? How much is it ?

Comment: @SamRubenAbraham Actually, the question just ask for all $n$.

Comment: I think we need to find a closed form

Comment: Ok...............

Comment: Maybe you can use the following : $ \frac{i}{2} (x_1 + x_i) + x_1 $ if it follows a pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One idea is to deal with $x_1$ separately in order to use stars and bars on $x_2,x_3,x_4$. For example you fix $x_1=0$ and then you have $x_2+x_3+x_4=n$ or you fix $x_1=1$ and then get $x_2+x_3+x_4=n-2$ and so on and so forth. This then generates the summations
$$x_2+x_3+x_4=n-2i$$
which have ${n-2i+2 \choose 2}$ solutions. Thus as $x_1$ can be a number between $0$ and $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ you get the summation
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{n-2i+2 \choose 2}.$$

Comment: I think this won't be the most optimum solution in case of bigger values of n and relatively small $x_1$. Sure it does represent a way but Angina's answer is far more efficient i suppose?

Comment: Well: generating functions are a much powerful tool which I personally really like, but I cannot teach those in high-school. It really depends on what level you like to solve the problem.

Comment: Ohh, I am sorry, I was unfamiliar about that, in our high schools we do learn them. And  yes this is correct and explains the user well

Answer (score 6):

I would use the generating function. If $a_n$ is the number of solutions for a given $n$
then
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n X^n=\frac1{(1-X^2)(1-X)^3}=\frac1{(1+X)(1-X)^4}
=\frac{A}{1+X}+\frac{f(X)}{(1-X)^4}$$
in partial fractions where $f(X)$ is a cubic polynomial. Now find $A$ and $f(X)$ etc.

Comment: Could you expand the first equality in a few more steps?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recurrence to solve this, as you already mentioned ( #(M) is the number of elements of the set M)

$$S(n)=\#(\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)| x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 =n, x_1\ge 0,x_2\ge 0,x_3\ge 0,x_4\ge 0\})$$
$$E(n)=\#(\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)| 2x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 =n, x_1\ge 0,x_2\ge 0,x_3\ge 0,x_4\ge 0\})$$
$$O(n)=\#(\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)| (2x_1+1)+x_2+x_3+x_4 =n, x_1\ge 0,x_2\ge 0,x_3\ge 0,x_4\ge 0\})$$

So $E(n)$ counts the tuples where the first component is even and $O(n)$ counts the tuples where the first component is odd.

We have $$S(n)=E(n)+O(n)$$
$S(n)$ can be calculated with the stars and bars method, we get
$$S(n)={ n+3\choose 3}$$

From the definitions wee see that
$$O(n)=E(n-1)$$
So we get
$$E(n)={ n+3\choose 3}-E(n-1)$$
and further
$$E(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{ i+3\choose 3}(-1)^{n-i}$$

Note that ${ i+3\choose 3}$ is a polynomial of degree $3$, so a closed formula for this sum can be derived from the [Faulhaber formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) if we take into account that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1}i^p(-1)^{2n+1-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1}i^p-2\sum_{i=0}^{n}(2i)^p=\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1}i^p-2^{p+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n}i^p$$
So finally we get
$$E(2n+1)=\frac{4 {{n}^{3}}+21 {{n}^{2}}+35 n+18}{6}$$
and
$$E(2n)={ 2n+4\choose 3}-E(2n+1)=\frac{4 {{n}^{3}}+15 {{n}^{2}}+17 n+6}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

I can’t post my ask on new thread.

**Problem 1.** Let be $a$ is positive integer $(a\le 5)$. Define $\|1,1,1,a;n\|$ are Number of non-negative integer solutions of equation $\quad x_1+x_2+x_3+ax_4=n$

Proof

$\|1,1,1,a;n\|=\left\lfloor\dfrac{(n+2)(n+a+2)(2n+a+1)}{12a}\right\rfloor$

**Problem2.** Applies result on problem 1, Count number of triangles with edges are positive integers less than or equal $n$

---

My solution for problem 2.
Let $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are three edges of triangle sort order $1\le x_1\le x_2\le x_3\le n$

Get $\begin{cases}x_1=y_1+1;(y_1\ge 0) \\ x_2=x_1+y_2=y_1+y_2+1;(y_2\ge 0)\\ x_3=x_2+y_3=y_1+y_2+y_3+1;(y_3\ge 0)\end{cases}$
Because $x_1+x_2>x_3$ therefore
$2y_1+y_2+2>y_1+y_2+y_3+1\Rightarrow y_1\ge y_3\Leftrightarrow y_1=y_3+y_4;(y_4\ge 0)$
And $x_3=y_1+y_2+y_3+1=y_2+2y_3+y_4+1\le n$
Therefore $y_2+y_4+y_5+2y_3=n-1$ where $y_5\ge 0$
Ref problem 1. Number of triangles are $\|1,1,1,2;n-1\|=\left\lfloor\dfrac{(n+1)(n+3)(2n+1)}{24}\right\rfloor$

Return problem 1. I trying uses generating funtion
$G(x)=\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^3(1-x^a)}$ but not result.
Could you help me solve it?